# Should the question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/91120/34686 be un-deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Should the question ["Do the NPRMs & Final Rules preceding 1993 "alphabet" airspace re-designation indicate that these phrases were meant to exclude Class E "extensions"?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91120/do-the-nprms-final-rules-preceding-1993-alphabet-airspace-re-designation-ind) be un-deleted?

Note that it was apparently deleted by "community" because it received a single downvote, and no answers were posted within 30 days.  (See item 9 here: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) )

Note that a downvoter and/or close-voter cited a lack of links to relevant documents as the reason for his vote.  That has been now been addressed.  The question has also been streamlined.

---

Question has now been un-deleted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this question should be un-deleted.

It is answerable (and more easily now with the added links) and will no doubt be answered within 30 days if it is un-deleted.

Answers to this question might be highly relevant to answers to other related ASE questions such as [Does FAR 91.155c apply to class E surface extensions?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48103/does-far-91-155c-apply-to-class-e-surface-extensions) and  [Does an SVFR clearance extend to Echo surface extensions?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/does-an-svfr-clearance-extend-to-echo-surface-extensions) and [Which parts of class E airspace can an ultralight (part 103) fly in without prior ATC authorization?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-parts-of-class-e-airspace-can-an-ultralight-part-103-fly-in-without-prio) and [What is the primary reason that the non-towered airports ACV, TVL, SGU, BIH, and SIT/PASI have E4 extensions to E2 airspace?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63970/what-is-the-primary-reason-that-the-non-towered-airports-acv-tvl-sgu-bih-and) .

If so, it is much better to have the content consolidated in a single answer where it can be linked to from other answers, rather than added in a duplicate fashion to multiple other answers.

The FAA's original intent during a specific rule-making action, which is still having significant effects on aviation in the US and is still generating relevant questions to ASE, is within the logical scope of ASE.

The question is not a duplicate of any ASE question and appropriate answers would not be duplicates of any ASE answers, because the question is not about any later (post-September 16 1993, the effective date of the "alphabet" airspace re-designation) rulings or other issuances from the FAA.

Likewise, answers to this question could not serve as complete self-contained answers to any of the other ASE questions noted above, or other similar questions, because factors other than the FAA's original intent also come into play when considering the current interpretation of regulations.  Therefore the question is sufficiently distinct from any other ASE question to justify un-deletion.

Please vote to un-delete.  Please vote directly on the un-deleting the question if you have those privileges, and please upvote this meta answer to show your agreement.

PS-- as to why I am posting this q and a here-- from [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) :

> If your post was deleted by high-reputation users or by the Community
> user, it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted (more if
> it's a question and it was popular) - politely asking for this on the
> per-site meta may attract the necessary votes if you make a good case
> for why the question should be restored

---

Question has now been un-deleted, thanks.